# GROUP BY with Distinct and Count for Active Record (Rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using: Rails 2.3.8 ruby 1.8.7

How can I convert the following query into Rails (Active-Record)

#### MYSQL

```
SELECT distinct source_code, count(source_code)
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
```

Returns =>

```
| source_code | count |
| ABC         | 16    |
| XYZ         | 2     |
```

#### Rails Attempt

```
Model.find(:all, :select => "distinct source_code, count(source_code)", 
                 :group => 1)

=> [Model source_code: "ABC">, Model source_code: "XYZ">]
```

As you can see, count is missing from the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL statement doesn't require the `DISTINCT` clause as the `GROUP BY` clause will return distinct `sourcecode` rows.

In rails 2.3.x you can get the desired result as follows:

```
Model.count(:group => :source_code)

# returns an ordered hash
{
  "ABC" => 16,
  "XYZ" => 2
}
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a way to do it.  Thank you!

Comment: What about Rails 3.2.13 ?? I am getting normal ActiveRecord Array but not Ordered Hash.btw, I want the actual records instead of count